# Schedule Stripe Transfers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, stripe-payments, sidekiq

I'm new to Rails and want to schedule payments in a Rails 4 application to happen at a future date using Stripe.

Customer A pays for a service from Recipient B in 3 days. The transfer is thus scheduled in 3 days + duration of the service.

Has someone used Sidekiq for this kind of operations? Is it a good fit or are there other gems out best suited for this kind of operations?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at a few things:

1. Payola https://www.payola.io/
2. Mastering Modern Payments https://www.masteringmodernpayments.com/
3. The SaaS Railskit https://railskits.com/saas/

Hopefully one or more of those will help you solve your problem.

Comment: Started looking at #2 it's great so far, thanks for the advice.